# unable to match a pattern though declared

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below Sample XML.

```
<toc>
<toc-part>
<toc-div>

<toc-item num="IV."><toc-title>New</toc-title><toc-pg>1.065</toc-pg><page number="1"/></toc-item>
</toc-div>
</toc-part>
</toc>
<section>
    <para>
        This is content<page number="3"/>
    </para>
</section>
```

here from the `section`, I'm trying to get the first page number value using the below XSL.

```
 <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:call-template name="pageCount"/>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="pageCount" match="//page[1]">
<div class="number">
<xsl:value-of select="./@number"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

but it is showing null.

current output `<div class="number"></div>`
Expected output `<div class="number">1</div>`

Here i'm using this method since, i need to do some mathematical operations on the first and second `page number`.

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix this.

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQj)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your "expected" output should be 1 (the first `page` element in the entire document) rather than 3 (the first `page` element in the section you're currently looking at)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a named template does not change the context. I am not sure why you need the named template, but if you must, change it to:

```
<xsl:template name="pageCount">
    <div class="number">
        <xsl:value-of select="(//page/@number)[1]"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Updated demo: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQj/1

Answer (score 3):

`call-template` does not change the context node, so you're calling the pageCount template with a context node of `section`, which does not have a `number` attribute.

Instead of calling the template by name you need to *apply* it to the relevant element:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::page[1]"/>
```

and make the match pattern more general, e.g. `page` instead of `//page[1]`. Using `apply-templates` *does* change the context as required.

You may want to consider using a *mode* on the template if you need to handle the same elements differently in other cases.

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pageCount"
        select="descendant::page[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="pageCount" match="page">
  <div class="number">
    <xsl:value-of select="./@number"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Edit: If you genuinely do want *every* `section` to pull the number off the same `page` element (the first one in the *whole document* as opposed to the first one in *that section*) then you could apply templates to `(//page)[1]` instead of `descendant::page[1]`.

Note the parentheses here - `(//page)[1]` is not the same as `//page[1]`.  The former selects at most one node (the first `page` in the document), the latter may select more than one (every `page` element that is the first `page` in its respective parent, so in your example this would be both pages numbered 1 *and* 3).

Answer (score 1):

According to spec:

> The match, mode and priority attributes on an xsl:template element do
>   not affect whether the template is invoked by an xsl:call-template
>   element.

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 2.0. The rather unfortunate formulation above appears in the XSLT 1.0 specification. In XSLT 2.0 they phrased it much better as: "*The match, mode and priority attributes on an xsl:template element have no effect when the template is invoked by an xsl:call-template instruction.*" http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#named-templates